# I want make ol.js file. How to make full package ol.js?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I want to make ol.js, like ol cdn file or result of v5.3-dist.

Example, provided ol site, is not i want. Ol example just make application, part of ol.

I want full ol.js.

How to make ol.js? webpack? parcel?

Comment: perhaps this issue might help: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8949

Comment: another thing to try: https://github.com/geoblocks/legacylib

Comment: @geocodezip wow.... thank you very much!!